# Lines disappearing intermittently from both Terminal and Emacs

Tags: 11.10, command-line, display, emacs

I'm having trouble even finding the right search terms to diagnose this problem. It's also hard to reproduce on my own machine.

When I enter a command in the terminal, occassionally I will see no results at all. I won't even see a new prompt. It seems like the display is getting corrupted. All it takes to clear it up is hitting `Enter` again. Then I will see a (second) new prompt, and the result of the previous command.

A similar thing is happening in Emacs. When I switch to a buffer, or scroll, occassionally there are several missing lines, or even portions of lines. If I highlight those lines, they become visable again.

I'm not even sure what system controls rendering in both Emacs and Terminal. I don't notice the problem in any other applications (other than those, I mainly use Chrome).

Comment: It just happened in Emacs and I was going to take a screenshot, but as soon as I opened the unity menu, the missing characters reappeared. So it seems to clear up whenever the screen is refreshed somehow.

Comment: Does it happen in a console (when you hit CTRL+ALT+F1), or only under GUI?. Have you tried alternative console emulators (like guake, konsole or any other)?.

Comment: Only when inside Unity. I haven't tried alternate consoles. It's been happening a lot in irb (Ruby's REPL).

Comment: At this point it looks like a bug in either compiz/graphic drivers or gnome console. Trying alternative consoles could help in narrowing it.

Comment: Ok, I've started using guake and I like it so far. We'll see if it has the same issuee...

Comment: When it's not "warmed-up", guake takes a long time to show up. If I 've just used it, it opens right up, but after using other applications for a while, it can take a few seconds to show.

Comment: I am using NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (Recommended)

Comment: If guake is working then it's likely a problem with gnome console, you should opne a bug. For a light weight terminal, I like lxterminal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the NVidia drivers. Here are some solutions to the similar question:

[Gnome-terminal doesn't refresh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89606/gnome-terminal-doesnt-refresh)