# Screen not refreshing after Nvidia driver install on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, command-line, nvidia

After installation of new Nvidia driver for Quadro 400 on my PC, refreshing is not proper any more, especially with the terminal. Even after trying a few solutions such as suggested in the post: [Gnome-terminal doesn't refresh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89606/gnome-terminal-doesnt-refresh)
the issue is not resolved. I cannot uninstall Nvidia driver as it is required for the software I use.

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix that issue. Since the buffering seems to be an issue I tried the following:

In *Compizconfig-settings-manager-> advanced search-> workarounds (in plugins on right)-> Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint (tick)*

enabling this setting alone seems to solve my issue completely :)